# WCF Generated Client vs Web Request

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, httpwebrequest, dotnet-httpclient

I just had a general question about WCF Client generated by svcutil from a WSDL versus making a call using HttpClient with the correct parameters. I didn't even know WCF existed until a recent integration with an external API. They provided us with a WSDL and I was able to generate the client in C# using the svcutil command, I imported it into my project and added the bindings in my config and everything worked perfectly. I was able to call it using the following mockup below.

```
using (ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient())
{
    System.Xml.XmlElement resp = client.GetAllItems(new ItemRequest() { Key = "License Key"});
    var items = DataSerializer.DeserializeXml<ExternalItemCollection>(resp.InnerXml);
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        _logger.LogInfo("Item Id is" + item.Id);
    }
}
```

The only issue with the generated client is that the call "client.GetAllItems()" takes about 12,000ms to complete, if I run the service through another program (like SOAP UI) it returns the XML string in about 3,000ms. I have no clue what the overhead is with the generated client (like I said never used WCF before this hahaha) but since it is a generated and I don't have any control over the WSDL I've been looking at ways to optimize it. My assumption is that since all the calls generated return "System.Xml.XmlElement" which makes me thing it does some sort of deserialization and parsing under the hood, but I can't for the life of me figure out why the entire call is taking almost 4 times as long compared to SOAP UI.

I decided to try recreating the entire request in POSTMAN, just setting the headers and body and that returned within 3,000ms. So I decided to write a PoC and created the entire request using the HttpClient library with the correct headers and body. This entire request returned within 3,000ms.

```
using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("apikey", request.Key);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("SOAPAction", "http://url.for.wcf/GetAllItems");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "text/xml");
    var getAllItemsReq = $@"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
    <soapenv:Header>
          <web:AuthInfo>
             <web:LicenseKey>{request.Key}</web:SiteID>
          </web:AuthInfo>
       </soapenv:Header>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <web:GetAllItems>
             <web:status>Current</web:status>
          </web:GetAllItems>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>";
    var resp = client.PostAsync("https://api.external.vendor/service.svc", new System.Net.Http.StringContent(getAllItemsReq, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml"));
    resp.Wait();
    resp.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var xmlResp = resp.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    xmlResp.Wait();
    var xmlReader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(xmlResp.Result));
    xmlReader.ReadToDescendant("GetAllItemsResponse");
    return xmlReader.ReadInnerXml();
}
```

I guess my question here, is there any big issue doing it VIA an HttpClient rather than using the WCF Client generated by the WSDL provided by external vendor? Or if anyone has any suggestions on what I can do to optimize the WCF calls to not take 4x as long as a web request?

Thank you!

Client Config

```html
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IExternalService" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://website.com/myService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IExternalService"
            contract="IExternalService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IExternalService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Could you please check your numbers?! Based on the last sentence I assume that you wanted to write 12 000 ms not 1 200ms. Am I right?

Comment: @PeterCsala Yes sorry you are right. I missed a 0 hahaha. On average the call takes about 12 seconds +- 1000ms when using the classes generated by svcutil from the WSDL. Using HttpClient takes ~ 3 seconds +- 500ms.

Comment: Why do you use blocking code (`.Wait`, `.Result`) for HttpClient?

Comment: Can you share with us the wsdl file as well? along with your client config?

Comment: It does take a bit of time to load for the first time, since you have to initialize configurations such as IIS and ChannelFactory. Do you still have this problem after the first time ?

Comment: @PeterCsala That was just an example (PoC) of me trying to implement it in the existing flow to see if it would help, the WSDL generated non async calls so I had to make the flow all synchronous. And unfortunately I can't share the WSDL but it looks pretty standard to existing WSDL examples I've seen on the web, the client config I've attached to the original post, thanks!

Comment: @Jiayao Our rate limit is 4 threads so I am running the retrieval for a different item set on 4 different threads at the same time, but each thread instantiates its own "using (ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient())", but it makes 3 sequential calls using the same client and all 3 calls takes the same amount of time (1 and 2 are the same call with different parameters, and 3 is a seperate call), all around 12 seconds using WCF and around 3 seconds using HttpClient